# How to add two columns with one header and textbox in each in html table

Tags: html, html-table

I want to create a table should which contain two column with one header and one textbox each.

Here is the link of my needed table image..

[image: Sample table Image]

I the above table ..`Name` is header and `My First and Last Name` is text box. Like this next are their, one header and one textbox.

Here is my html table:

```
<body>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> <font color="#008eff" size="4px"> 1. Location of your  Hotel/Resort/Property </font> </th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><th>Name <td> <input type="text"></td><td>Designation</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><th>Organization</th><td><input type="text"></td><td>  </td><td>  </td></tr>
    <tr><th>Email</th><td><input type="text"></td><td>  </td><td>  </td></tr>
    <tr><th>Hotel/Resort/Property Name</th><td><input type="text"></td><td>Website address</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

But I am not able to create the exact table as in picture. Please help me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this: <kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JTmMa/1/)</kbd>

**CSS**

```
.header {
    color: #008eff;
    font-size: 13pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

input {
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="header">1. Location of your Hotel/Resort/Property</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="bold">Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td class="bold">Designation</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bold">Organization</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bold">Email</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bold">Hotel/Resort/Property Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td class="bold">Website address</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: how to decrease the height of **1. Location of your Hotel/Resort/Property**

Comment: @user3617097 you can check my code for decreasing the height.!! `.heading` in css you can specify the font-size you need

Comment: can i specify the height of <tr> table row? as in my image all rows are of same height

Comment: @user3617097 that's because of the <p> tag. You could use: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JTmMa/1/)

Answer (score 3):

although slightly different than the attached image i think spanning over 4 columns is more right visually,

like this

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th colspan=4 align="left"> <font color="#008eff" size="4px" > 1. Location of your  Hotel/Resort/Property </font> </th>


</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`colspan="2"`** in your first **`th tag`**.

```
<tr>
    <th colspan="2"> <font color="#008eff" size="4px"> 1. Location of your  Hotel/Resort/Property </font> </th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>  
</tr>
```

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6USPA/)**</kbd>

Use **`colspan`** when you want to merge columns. and Use **`rowspan`** for merge rows. read [HTML table tag](http://www.way2tutorial.com/html/html_table_tutorial.php).

Comment: sir one more thing i want **Name ** **Organization** to be in color like **<th>** .How do it?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick. Use Colspan to merge the columns and don't use  tag again in second

```
<body>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"> <font color="#008eff" size="4px"> 1. Location of your  Hotel/Resort/Property </font> </th>

        <th  colspan="2"></th>


    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td> <b>Name</b><td> <input type="text"></td><td>Designation</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Organization</b></td><td><input type="text"></td><td>  </td><td>  </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type="text"></td><td>  </td><td>  </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hotel/Resort/Property Name</td><td><input type="text"></td><td>Website address</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> <font color="#008eff" size="4px"> 1. Location of your  Hotel/Resort/Property </font> </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Name <input type="text"></td><td>Designation<input type="text"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Organization <input type="text"></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email <input type="text"></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hotel/Resort/Property Name <input type="text"></td><td>Website address <input type="text"></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
width:700px;
}
table, th, td
{
border: 3px solid white;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
color:black;
}
th{
text-align:left;
}
input{
    float:right;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RcTB7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

**Demo:**

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2fpU7/4/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="heading">  1. Location of your  Hotel/Resort/Property 
            </th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Myfirstname and lastname"/>
                </td>
                <th>Designation</th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="My Designation name"/>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Organization</th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="My Organization"/>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="My Email ID"/>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Hotel/Resort/Property Name</th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="My Organization"/>
            </td>
            <th>Website address</th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="My Website address"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.heading
{
    color:#0083ff;
    font-size:12pt;
     background-color: #eee;
}
td,th
{

    text-align:left;
     background-color: #eee;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**P.S :**

The Mistakes in your code

- Don't use `<font>` tag as it is deprecated. **[To know more click here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/html_401/html4-ref/article.php/3460291)**
- Have a practice of using stylesheet.

To use Stylesheet you should know about two things they are `ID` and `Class`

ID is used to give style to a particular element,

whereas Class is used wherever you want the same style in different elements.

**[To know about Class & ID Click here..!!](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/)**

**[Advantages of Using CSS](http://www.wmtips.com/css/advantages-using-css.htm)**